# How to query based on multiple relations between columns - MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have four columns in a `properties` table: `property_id`, `value`, `id`, `material_id`.

I also have an array of properties: `Array $properties`

The schema is a bit complicated, because I want to find the `material_id` based on the matching properties.

An example:

```
$properties = array(['property_id'=>1,'value'=>3],['property_id'=>2,'value'=>6],['property_id'=>3,'value'=>4]);
```

Example table output:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+
| id | material_id | property_id | value |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |           1 |           3 |     5 |
|  2 |           1 |           3 |     5 |
|  3 |           1 |           3 |     5 |
|  4 |           2 |           1 |     3 |
|  5 |           2 |           2 |     6 |
|  6 |           2 |           3 |     4 |
| 10 |           4 |           1 |     9 |
| 11 |           4 |           2 |     3 |
| 12 |           4 |           3 |     6 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+
```

Now, I need `material_id` that satisfies all the properties. How can I do that..? Do I need to use `exist` statement of MySQL?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear? It seems like the properties array already includes material_id...

Comment: Now, it's correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Now, for each element in your array you will want to run a statement that looks  like this:

```
SELECT material_id FROM properties WHERE property_id = 2 AND value = 3;
```

Do you need help on the php code also? You could run a for each loop, but I will need to know what way you are using to communicate with your database for more specifics.

edit

```
foreach ($properties as $foo => $bar)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT material_id FROM properties WHERE ';  

    foreach ($bar as $key => $value)
    {
        $sql .= $key .' = '. $value .' AND ';
    }

    $sql .= 'true';

   *run your PDO code on $sql here*
}
```

Comment: Actually, I am using PHP. Please take a look at the updated example.

Comment: This is the kind of query you will have to write. Are you using mysqli or PDO to connect to mysql?

Comment: PDO, yes. I'm using PDO.

Comment: Please now look at the example schema

Comment: The count of number of properties can change. How do I deal with that..?

Comment: Then it becomes more complex, although it is still possible. I will get back to you on that.

Comment: Appreciate the help. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

On behalf of performance, **it's not a good idea** to **run a query per array's value**. If you have an oversized array things can get pretty slower.

So, best solution can be to build a single query including all conditions presented on `$properties` array:

```
<?php

$properties = array(['property_id'=>1,'value'=>3],['property_id'=>2,'value'=>6],['property_id'=>3,'value'=>4]);

$qCondition = [];
foreach($properties as $prop) {
    $q = sprintf("(property_id = %d AND value = %d)", $prop["property_id"], $prop["value"]);
    $qCondition[] = $q;
}

// assuming that your database table name is 'materials'
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM materials WHERE (" . implode(" OR ", $qCondition) . ")");

echo $sql;
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM materials 
WHERE ((property_id = 1 AND value = 3) OR (property_id = 2 AND value = 6) OR (property_id = 3 AND value = 4))
```

Therefore, you need to **run only one single query** to **get all desired rows**.

You can play with suggested solution here: http://ideone.com/kaE4sw

Comment: Actually, I need to select all the rows with the given properties and check if they all have the same `material_id` and if true then get that `material_id`. That's not possible with `or`. I guess we need some PHP coding too on the result set.

Comment: Ok. So, once you have the result from the above query, you must go through results (using php) and compare if they all have the same material_id.

Comment: Yup, I was looking for an SQL only way. But, apparently it doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually, I think I have a 'SQL only solution' in mind... I'll test it later and if it works I'll share it with you.

Comment: That'll be great!